# How to get month from date in Zend Framework select?

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, select

How can I select the month portion of a date in a Zend Framework select statement?  I want to use it similarly as DATEPART(month, datefield) in SQL.  I also want to group totals by month as well.

Her is my Zend select sql:

```
    $where = new Where ();
    $where->greaterThanOrEqualTo('date', $start_date);
    $where->lessThanOrEqualTo('date', $end_date);   
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(function(Select $select) use 
    ($where){    
    $select->columns(array('date', 'count' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('COUNT(*)')));

    $select->where($where); 
    $select->group('date');    //  I want to group by month here.
    $select->order('date asc'); 
    }); 
    return $resultSet;
```

In this example I wish to select the month portion of date and also group by the month.  I an fairly new to Zend and finding it hard to get documentation on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, the following modification should work:

```
$where = new Where ();
$where->greaterThanOrEqualTo('date', $start_date);
$where->lessThanOrEqualTo('date', $end_date);   
$resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(function(Select $select) use 
($where){    
$select->columns(array('datemonth' => 'DATEPART(month,date)', 'count' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('COUNT(*)')));

$select->where($where); 
$select->group('datemonth'); 
$select->order('date asc'); 
}); 
return $resultSet;
```

Comment: I've not used ZF2, but shouldn't the `'DATEPART(month,date)'` part be in `\Zend\Db\Sql\Expression`? Like this: `'datemonth' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('DATEPART(month,date)')`